# Any academic research/term for (some) men's preference for muscular female bodies?

Tags: terminology, sexuality

While I was searching for articles on the correlates of attraction to female "feminine" faces I ran into some non-academic discussions on the attraction that some men apparently have for muscular women, e.g. [on quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-am-I-attracted-to-girls-who-are-very-muscular) or on [bodybuilding.com forms](https://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=4316883&pagenumber=1), where some of the folk opinion (fairly predictably) was that such men are "closet homo" etc.

I'm at a loss how to search for any academic works on this topic, i.e. what's some terminology used; is there any academic research on this phenomenon at all?

As a related matter, there is some academic research on the nature of visual preferences of bisexual males, e.g. [using swimsuit images](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22875715), but only typical male/female images were used in that paper, not anything more "in-between", e.g. in terms of muscularity (or facial features). It's also quite easy to find reseach on the culturally-expected phenomenon ["women drawn to men with muscles"](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-sex-muscles1/women-drawn-to-men-with-muscles-idUSEIC04599320070710) or [articles trying to limit/disprove that](https://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/news/20000810/attraction-to-muscular-men). There's an article in theconversation.com ["Why do we find muscular women wildly perplexing?"](https://theconversation.com/why-do-we-find-muscular-women-wildly-perplexing-21846) but it doesn't even acknowledge the phenomenon that some men apparently are attracted to muscular women; it just rails against cultural standards etc.

In a case Wikipedia having surprisingly little google juice, on the 5th page of google results; I discovered its article on ["muscle worship"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_worship), which does contain some Latin-ish (how else) academic terms: sthenolagnia (="sexual arousal from displaying strength or muscles") and cratolagnia ("arousal from strength"). But these terms can simply refer to the "worship" participants fitting culturally-expected roles; I did find there that it's supposedly very prevalent among gay men, but there's no citation to back that up, and in any case it isn't what I was looking for. A similarly uncited statement is that

> Many other sites are oriented towards straight men who enjoy worshipping female bodybuilders and other fit, muscular women, either virtually or by arranging for in-person sessions.

Ok, no academic took interest in this phenomenon, ever?

Comment: I see there's also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attraction_to_transgender_people but it makes no mention of muscles.